# How to reuse a JS function on different HTML elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 squares in a `<table>` and I want that when I click one, it become black and the other don't.

My current code is working but I gave them the same function and `id`, so when I click the first, it work well, but when I click the second, it's the first one that changes. 
I know whats wrong, but I don't know how to correct it without having to create a function for each `id`.

Let's say I want 100 squares, I won't write one function to each one, so what can I do?

```js
function myFunc() {
  var element = document.getElementById("cc");
  element.classList.toggle("th");
}
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: solid black 1px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.th {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th onclick="myFunc(this)" id="cc"></th>
    <th onclick="myFunc(this)" id="cc"></th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Post the code you have so far, within the question

Comment: You probably need to pass a reference of the thing being clicked - `onclick="myFunc(this)"`

Comment: adding "this" dont change anything :/  can you give detail pls

Comment: @SamuelFyckes Well, just adding `this` won't do much. What did you do with `this` ounce it was passed into your function?

Comment: You have two elements with the same id `cc`. JavaScript expects IDs to be unique, so `document.getElementById('cc')` will *always* pick the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, and more important: `id` must be unique, thats why it is called id (identifier).

Said that, I will show you two options to solve your question:

**1. The better option**:
Don't add any inline (direct in HTML) `onclick` listener. Add a
common class to all `<th>`, then in Javascript add a single listener
to each element that has the class, and use `this` inside the function, since `this` scope will be the clicked element.

Example:

```js
let allTh = document.querySelectorAll(".clickableTh").forEach(x => x.onclick = myFunc)


function myFunc() {
   this.classList.toggle("th");
}
```

```css
table, th, td {
   border:solid black 1px;     
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
}
.th {
  background-color:black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class="clickableTh"></th>
    <th class="clickableTh"></th>
    <th class="clickableTh"></th>
    <th class="clickableTh"></th>
    <th class="clickableTh"></th>
    <th id="cc" class="notClickableTh"></th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**2. Keeping your current structure**:
As said in the comments, you pass `this` as parameter (`onclick="myFunc(this)"`), then inside `myFunc` you don't need to find the element, you'll already have it in as parameter.

Click below to see the snippet code of example

```js
function myFunc(elem) {
   elem.classList.toggle("th");
}
```

```css
table, th, td {
   border:solid black 1px;     
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
}
.th {
  background-color:black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th onclick="myFunc(this)"></th>
    <th onclick="myFunc(this)"></th>
    <th onclick="myFunc(this)"></th>
    <th onclick="myFunc(this)"></th>
    <th onclick="myFunc(this)"></th>
    <th id="cc"></th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

For less markup you can bind the click event on all `th`

```js
var th = document.getElementsByTagName("th");
for (var i = 0; i < th.length; i++) {
  th[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("th");
  });
}
```

```css
th,
td {
  border: solid black 1px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.th {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function is storing the first square in a variable with the `cc` identifier.

Instead, you should pass a reference of the element clicked and store that element in the variable. That way, the element clicked will be toggled.

```
function myFunc(ref) {
   var element = document.getElementById(ref.id).innerHTML;
   element.classList.toggle("th");
}
```

Notice that must also add `this` to the call of the function.